# Not able to read nested json array in SPLUNK

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am using "spath" to read json structure from a log file.

```
{"failure_reason":null,"gen_flag":"GENERATED","gen_date":"2020-02-15","siteid":"ABC","_action":"Change","order":"123"}
```

I am able to parse above json.

However, "spath" function is not able to read nested array inside that json:

```
{"failure_reason":"[{"module":"Status Report","reason":"Status Report is not available","statusCode":"503"}]","gen_flag":"GENERATED_PARTIAL","gen_date":"2020-02-15","siteid":"ABC","_action":"Change","wonum":"321"}.
```

please help!

Answer (score 0):

Your event is not valid JSON. A JSON array should not be surrounded by `"`s.

Copy your event into any of the following JSON validators, and confirm that it is incorrect.

- https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
- https://jsonlint.com/
- https://jsonformatter.org/

Now, try with the corrected event.

```
{"failure_reason":[{"module":"Status Report","reason":"Status Report is not available","statusCode":"503"}],"gen_flag":"GENERATED_PARTIAL","gen_date":"2020-02-15","siteid":"ABC","_action":"Change","wonum":"321"}
```

You can see that `spath` works correctly with the modified JSON with the following search.

```
| makeresults 
| eval raw="{\"failure_reason\":[{\"module\":\"Status Report\",\"reason\":\"Status Report is not available\",\"statusCode\":\"503\"}],\"gen_flag\":\"GENERATED_PARTIAL\",\"gen_date\":\"2020-02-15\",\"siteid\":\"ABC\",\"_action\":\"Change\",\"wonum\":\"321\"}" 
| spath input=raw
```

If you need a way to pre-process your event to remove the `"`s from the array, you may be able to try the following, which may remove the extra `"`s. This is really dependent on the structure of the event, and may not be 100%, but should be enough to get you started. Try to fix the format of the event at the source.

```
| makeresults | eval raw="{\"failure_reason\":\"[{\"module\":\"Status Report\",\"reason\":\"Status Report is not available\",\"statusCode\":\"503\"}]\",\"gen_flag\":\"GENERATED_PARTIAL\",\"gen_date\":\"2020-02-15\",\"siteid\":\"ABC\",\"_action\":\"Change\",\"wonum\":\"321\"}" 
| rex mode=sed field=raw "s/\"\[/[/" | rex mode=sed field=raw "s/\]\"/]/"
| spath input=raw
```